# Square numbers which can be written as two consecutive squares lined up

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, square-numbers

I would like to find a square whose digits are $n^2$ and $(n+1)^2$ lined up in this order.

$49$ is the only example I know, which has $2^2=4$ and $(2+1)^2=9$ lined up.

So basically, I would like to find a square in the sequence $14, 49, 916, 1625, 2536, \cdots$.

Google told me that there is no such number until $n=10^5$, so I suspect there is no such number except $49$, but I don't know how to prove it.

Also, my language ability is limited, so please tell me if there is a better way to phrase this question.

Comment: I think you have phrased the question well.

Comment: You want to find a positive integer $n$ such that $$\sqrt{10^{f(n)}n^2+(n+1)^2}\ \in\mathbb N$$
where $f(n)=\lfloor 1+\log_{10}(n+1)^2\rfloor$. It can be proven that $f(n)$ has to be odd.